# Validation Error

Tags: validation-rule

My requirement is I have to create 2 new fields on Lead object `'IsTopLevelAccount__c'`(Checkbox field) and `'Parent__c '`(Lookup field on account).
I map `'IsTopLevelAccount__c'` of lead with `'IsTopLevelAccount__c'` of account using standard mapping and via apex trigger I map 'Parent__c ' with the standard field `'Parent'` of the account which is parent account field.
There is an existing validation on the account object as follow:

```
OR(AND( 
    $User.BypassValidation__c = FALSE,
     OR( 
     ISPICKVAL( ProposedAccountType__c , "Customer" ), 
     ISPICKVAL( ProposedAccountType__c , "" ) 
     ), 
     IsTopLevelAccount__c = FALSE, 
    (ISBLANK( Parent.Id ))
    ),
    AND( 
    $User.BypassValidation__c = FALSE,
     OR( 
     ISPICKVAL( ProposedAccountType__c , "Customer" ), 
     ISPICKVAL( ProposedAccountType__c , "" ) 
     ), 
     IsTopLevelAccount__c = TRUE, 
     NOT((ISBLANK( Parent.Id ))) 
    )
    )
```

This validation checks during the account creation,either I mark as a top level account for this I  set `IsTopLevelAccount__c = TRUE` or I can add the parent account.
    On lead object I have created `'Parent__c '` field which is a lookup field and as I can not map lookup field with the standard account field,so I user trigger on account object(afterUpdate) which maps `'Parent__c'` with `'Parent'` which is standrd field of account as I mentioned already.
    This validation is working fine on Account object but when in lead conversion when I select an account in `'Parent__c'` field the it always throw me the validation error even if I provide the value in Parent__c.In logs I found that it always gives me Parent.Id as null not sure why?
    but weird thing is if I user `ISNULL(Parent.Id)` then validation is pass during the lead conversion but on the account object it throws the validation error again not sure why?

This is the weird behavior and I am nopt getting any clue how to solve this.I tried to use `OR((ISBLANK( Parent.Id ),(ISNULL( Parent.Id ))` but still it is not working.
Can anybody suggest why this is happening??

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Validation rules run before your after update trigger on Account

Comment: @cropredy ok.But I am trying to add the custom field there in order to bypass ISNULL(Parent.id) like  OR(ISBLANK( Parent.Id ),AccountValidationCheck__c=true)   AccountValidationCheck__c is a custom  formula field on lead object that maps with 'AccountValidationCheck__c' of account in this case it should consider ISNULL(Parent.id) but still it returens false there.Any suggession

Comment: user33671 - your question is extremely hard to follow and I would suggest you include a example of the data values as they exist on the Lead, and how they are mapped to Account - but not in paragraph form - use some graphical form

Comment: @cropredy Lead.IsTopLevelAccount__c ---->Mapped to ----->Account.IsTopLevelAccount__c via standard mapping

Lead.Parent__c---->Mapped to ----->Account.ParentId(Parent) via trigger.trigger is on lead on (afterupdate)

e.g.Create a lead 'Test' and add the Account 'Acc1' in 'Parent__c' when lead is converted into account it should map 'acc1' automatically on account but before it map,it always throws the validation error.

Comment: I dont know the option how to provide screenshot here

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to amend your question. There is a way to insert images

Comment: @cropredy please check the screenshot.In first screenshot,I have specified the value in lookup field.for now validation rule is disbale.in second screenshot on when account is created it maps with the standard field of account.In 3rd screenshot i have activated validation rule and specified the validation on convert lead.Ideally as pe rthe current validation it should not throw the error.let me know..

Comment: Can you please verify the `User` you are testing as does not have `BypassValidation__c` set to true? Also, please specify the `ProposedAccountType__c` since it does not appear in your screenshot.

Comment: @AdrianLarsonI have verified already.User does not have BypassValidation__c set to true.

Comment: @AdrianLarson ProposedAccountType is mentioned on Lead.Updating screenshot for the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user33671

It looks like you are running afoul of the [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=order%20of%20execution)

When Lead Conversion occurs, SFDC will

- Insert an Account with values mapped per Lead Mapping rules
- Run Before insert trigger on Account
- Run Validation Rules on Account
- Run after insert trigger on Account
- ... as per rest of Order of Execution

In your OP, you state you are using an after update trigger.  As you can see from the Order of Execution, you have to make the Account look valid before the Validation Rules run and the best way to do that is with a before insert trigger.

You are going to need to map `Lead.ParentId__c` field (type Text) to some `Account.ParentIdFromLeadConvert__c` field (type Text) in the Lead Mapping rules.  Then, your before insert trigger on Account can simply assign the value from `Account.ParentIdFromLeadConvert__c` to `Account.Parent__c`.

But `Lead.ParentID` can't be a formula field as formula fields can't be "Lead" mapped. You'll need to set it with either a before insert/update trigger on Lead or a Workflow/Process Builder Field Update (using the value of `Lead.Parent__c` as the source for the assignment).

Comment: I am using AfterUpdate trigger on Lead not on Account.are you suggesting  to use before insert on account? I have added the code that I have written.Please check..

Comment: Lead.ParentId__c  that i have used here is the formula field of type text which stores the value of  Parent__c(Parent Account) which is a lookup field and I have already mapped this field  with ConvertedAccountId__c of account.if I assign the value  ConvertedAccountId__c(Text)  to ParentId of account on before trigger,will it assign?

Comment: @user33671 `If I assign the value ConvertedAccountId__c(Text) to ParentId of account on before trigger,will it assign?` -- I don't see why not, in apex, you can assign strings to ID fields.

Comment: Thank you somuch I have added small code on account before insert trigger and it is working perfectly fine no weird validation error come.Thank You so much for your help.